# Performance implication in declaring variables JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Are there any performance(or otherwise) implications in doing this;

```
// ...
const greeting = `Hello, ${name}!`;
return greeting;
```

in comparison to doing just this;

```
// ...
return `Hello, ${name}!`;
```

Comment: Maybe half of a nanosecond, as the size of the script is slightly bigger.

Comment: Not significant. You can neglect

Comment: I think there is an actual difference, because JS variables are objects, containing some properties and methods. However in this case it's absolutely neglectable.

Comment: Regardless, I'd stick with the top example as it's easier to debug and the performance aspect is definitely unnoticeable unless you're looping a through an extreme amount of data

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality

Comment: If you want to know, then just **measure**. Also, I'm sure it will prove to be a total waste of your time to focus on such a small detail.

Comment: doesn't matter ... Focus on your actual task bro. you can definitely neglect it .

Comment: Wonderful Wonderful! Thanks everybody for the comments; quite insightful. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, assigning a value to a variable name and then returning that variable takes *slightly more* effort than simply returning the value. For a mini performance test, see:

(warning: the following will *block* your browser for a bit, depending on your specs)

```js
// references to "name" removed to provide a more minimal test:

const p0 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
  (() => {
    const greeting = `Hello!`;
    return greeting;
  })();
}
const p1 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
  (() => {
    return `Hello!`;
  })();
}
const p2 = performance.now();

console.log(p1 - p0);
console.log(p2 - p1);
```

The difference is quite small, but it's consistently there, at least in V8 - the overhead of the function call mostly overshadows it.

That said, this really sounds like premature optimization - it's probably better to aim for *code readability and maintainability*, and *then* fix performance issues *if and when* they pop up. If declaring a name for the returned value makes the code easier to read, it's probably a good idea to do so, even if it makes the script take a (completely insignificant) longer time to run.

Comment: While running this code, keep in mind that the first test (the one with the instantiation) will take a bit much longer because the V8 engine will compile the whole thing on the fly. If you switch the tests you will see that the time taken to run the two test cases will be the same (and sometimes the one with the instantiation will be shorter than the one without). It would be better to run them separately to have them in the same environment.